# Postgresql installation

Tags: postgresql

I'm going crazy with postgresql (9.1) installation on my server (debian) i have rent on gandi.net !
I did the `aptitude get-install postgresql postgresql-client` command.

I'm having this error when trying to execute psql command.

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've been searching on the web. And maybe the servers are not running. I don't know how to check and how to launch them.

My postgres command doesn't work either (command not found).

Any idea?

Comment: Somehow the install went bad otherwise postgres would be up and running. Suggestion: uninstall and reinstall but save and post the install's output so it can be analyzed and checked for errors. Other than that, read https://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database engine is not running.

```
service postgresql start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

to start the engine. I don't remember though if debian  initializes the data dir automatically.